# Microsoft visual studio 2008 setup project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a bunch of files and need to build MSI file /setup.exe file that put them on specific folder and run one file  of them that install a win32 service is that possible with micorosoft visual studio 2008 setp project ?

suppossing i have the following files:
file1,
file2
file3
file4

I need to put file1,file,file3 under c:\documents and setting\all users\my directory 
and run file4 which install a win32 service while running the setup or the msi is that possilbe ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's all possible.  Create a new deployment project and in the File View add the files from your project in the correct places.  You may need to mark your files as `Content = True` in the file properties (from the solution explorer) then I think they'll appear in the dropdown in the file view.

For a windows service, the executable needs to be able to install itself as a service from the command line anyway, so installing it from the MSI is easy as you just need a custom step to call your .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this with a standard [Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx). To add custom files and folders, check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x56s4w8x.aspx

For the base "All Users" folder, you will need to specify a [Special Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x.aspx), specifically the [CommonAppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992.aspx).

Specifying how to [install a Windows Service involves using a special component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  I'm not too happy with it, I much prefer [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).